# SharePoint 2013 - Give Anonymous Users access to specific page

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

When I click on either share, or advance under share, for a specific publishing page, I want to grant Anonymous Users access to this page.  what steps do I need to take in detail to enable this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can enable Anonymous Access by:

1)Going to Application Management in Central Administration, Highlight the WebApp where you want to enable Anonymous Authentication, Click on Authentication Providers, Click on the Zone where you want to enable Anonymous Access, then Check Enable Anonymous Access, Save.

2) Go to your Web Application and the top level of the site collection > Site Actions > Site Settings > Site Permissions > Anonymous Access > List and Library

After that you can set each of your page to give anonymous user permission to read your page

This [link](http://blog.drisgill.com/2009/11/sp2010-branding-tip-9-turn-on-anonymous.html) has a the above walkthrough with screen shots